# error in import pandas after installing it using pip

Tags: python, pandas

I installed pandas using pip and get the following message "pip install pandas
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pandas in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up..."

When I load up python and try to import pandas, it says module not found. Please help

Comment: Pip is probably installing it to a different location than what you're expecting. Do you have multiple Python installs on your machine? Have you tried using virtualenv?

Comment: Do any of the related questions to the right of here help?

Comment: try doing a `which pip` and `which python` and make sure that they are located in the same python directory (and contains the path you have above). It may be the case that you have multiple python versions on your operating system, where pip is installed on the non standard version and calling python executes the standard version [builtin with the OS ship] or vice versa. Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: I checked the directories of both python and pip and /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versio/2.7/bin/pip and python is at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
I'm using Mac os X 10.6.8

Answer (score 1):

Try to locate your pandas lib in /python*/lib/site-packages, add dir to your sys.path file.

Comment: How do I add to sys.path?

Answer (score 0):

Following the previous answer try this after opening a python shell:

```
import sys 
new_path = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages" # or wherever your pip install drops things
sys.path.append(new_path)
import pandas
```